# django compressor offline compressor missing key

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-compressor

I'm using Mezzanine with django-compressor and trying to use offline compress (thing work fine for dynamic compression), and s3.

At the moment I just wrap some simple css includes in my base template, ,which use the `{% static ... %}` tag for the url,  with `{% compress css %}`. I then issue the `python manage.py compress`. Upon visiting my site, I find that whether it works or not alternatives between refreshes!

Sometimes I get the exception

```
Exception Type: OfflineGenerationError
Exception Value:    
You have offline compression enabled but key "dd0452fbacfe30d826f76c02821b8e9a" is missing from offline manifest. You may need to run "python manage.py compress".
```

Then on the next refresh, the page loads and I can see the compressed css in CACHE dir of my s3 bucket. 10seconds later I refresh and get the error again. It's crazy.

I'm using `django-compressor==1.4`.